# ddrescue a non-solaris disk gets I/O error

Tags: solaris, scsi, disk-image, dd

I am trying to get a disk image of a SCSI disk using ddrescue on Solaris10 (Sparc).  The disk is non-solaris, and ddrescue gets an immediate I/O error (as does dd).  I used format to label the disk as Solaris, and now ddrescue reads it fine.  Is there any way to get the image without labelling the disk as Solaris?

Comment: by the way, the solaris format command (subcommand read) can read the disk, and finds no errors.

Comment: It would help if you tell precisely the command you run, and especially what device you use.

Answer (score 0):

As default ddrescue uses the kernel i/o to do the reads. If the kernel is only set up to support Spark disks, then this might be your problem.

You could try using the -d flag )direct disc access for input file) but you would then have to set the correct blocksize for the device (-b xxx).

Hope this works :)

Comment: ddrescue tells me the -d flag is not supported on this system. Is there a way to config the kernel to support non-solaris disks?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have no idea, tbh -might be a good idea to ask in #opensolaris or similar. urm, if it was linux, then I'd say make sure the correct drivers/fs were compiled into the kernel.
Are you sure the disk isn't BORKED?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the raw disk device with ddrescue? /dev/rdsk/xxx instead of /dev/dsk/xxx?